# Ordering the results of an file with ArrayList and compareTo

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compareto

I have to order an arrayList that contains lines from a file by account ID and then by salary to get this result:

```
CuentaAhorro   : 11111111A (Alicia)   Saldo  111,11
CuentaAhorro   : 12345678A (Lucas)    Saldo 5100,00
CuentaCorriente: 22222222B (Peio)     Saldo  222,22
CuentaAhorro   : 33333333C (Isabel)   Saldo 4433,33
CuentaCorriente: 33333333C (Isabel)   Saldo 3333,33
CuentaAhorro   : 87654321A (Asier)    Saldo 3000,00
```

My arrayList calls the compareTo method from Bank.java.

```
 public void ordenarCuentas() {

            Collections.sort(cuentas);

        }
```

The call is to the method compareTo in an abstract class called Account with the comparable interface:

```
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Cuenta unaCuenta) {

      Cliente unTitular = unaCuenta.titular;

      if(unTitular.toString().equals(unaCuenta.titular.toString()) == true) {
            return 0;
//         if(saldo < unaCuenta.saldo) {
//             return -1;
//          } else if (saldo > unaCuenta.saldo) {
//             return 1;
//          } else {
//             return 0;
//          }
      }
        return -1;    
}
```

I need to check if the object 'Cuenta unaCuenta' passed as a parameter has the same account number as another and then sort by the amount of money in the account, however I am not sure how to get the condition right, as you can see, with the commented if I get the salary in the right descending order but not the account IDs.

The object Cuenta unaCuenta contains titular which contains account number and name.

The object Cliente unTitular contains the account number and name.

Could somebody lend me a hand please?

Comment: As someone who doesn't speak spanish it is really hard for me to wrap my head around what is what. I have no idea which variable represents accounts ID and of what type it is. (I'm just assuming its spanish, sorry if it is not).

Comment: You need to first compare the account number. Only if that is equal you need to compare the account balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the comments. Next time i'll translate the Spanish code to English. I'll post my solution incase someone comes across this question.

(in my case I had to use a comparable interface and a compareTo method).

```
 @Override
   public int compareTo(Account anAccount) {

        String b = this.title.toString();
        Client aTitle = anAccount.title;
        String c = aTitle.toString();

        if(b.compareTo(c) == 0) {
            if(balance == anAccount.balance) {
               return 0;
            } else if (balance < anAccount.balance) {
               return 1;
            } else {
               return -1;
            }
           } 
            return b.compareTo(c);

         }
```

As stated, I had to compare both object values first, if they are the same I then check the condition of the balance to change the order.

```
-1 = object is less than the parameter.
0 = when both objects are the same.
1 = the object is more than the parameter.
```

And I called the method from the Bank.java class with:

```
Collections.sort(cuentas);
```

Where cuentas is the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able understand it very clearly because of language barrier 
But if you have a arraylist you can call sort method on it an pass a comparator to get the desired sorting , something like below.

**It is just to give you an idea**

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.sort(new Comparator() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            if(o1.account.equals(o2.account)) return 0;
            return o1.amount - o2.amount;
        }

     });
```

**as Lambda**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.sort((o1,o2) -> 
                          if(o1.account.equals(o2.account)) return 0;
                          return o1.amount - o2.amount; 
     });
```